# How to redirect link with question mark

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect:

https://www.example.com/wiki/?t=1234 to https://www.example.com/vb/showthread.php?t=1234

"1234" is hundreds of pages with different numbers

I try in .htaccess but doesn't seem to work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=[0-9]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The number may occur once or more in query string ([0-9]+)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wiki\/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} t=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /vb/showthread.php?t=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```